# How do we display the circled area of an image in html?

Tags: javascript, css

I have an image which is in rectangular shape. However, I would like achieve an end result as below.

[image]

How can I achieve this in CSS / javascript?

Comment: May be  `border-radius: 50%` will be useful: http://jsfiddle.net/PG656/

Comment: Why is everybody posting the same answer. Yes. Border-radius 50% . we get it. all the answers are duplicates. nothing unique

Comment: border-radius works only with FF, Chrome and IE 9. For earlier versions of IE use CSS3PIE or other progressive behaviours for IE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it using border-radius:

```
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px; 
    /* width and height can be anything, as long as they're equal */
}
```

For more info check out this **[article](http://davidwalsh.name/css-circles)**.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an `img` tag, than simply use the snippet below to make it round

```
.container_class img {
   border-radius: 50%;
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YSVMT/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/YSVMT/1/) (With border)

---

The above examples will give you a perfect circle as `height` = `width`, if you want an elliptical shape, as you've provided in your question, than you can simply increase the `width` of your `img` tag like

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YSVMT/3/)

> Note: `border-radius` is a CSS3 property, as of now it is widely
>   supported across browsers, still if IE is a game spoiler for you,
>   there are polyfills available like [CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Use `border-radius: 50%;` not supported in IE8 though.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xdcSq/1/)**

**The HTML:**

```
<img src="http://coolvibe.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Portrait-Alexander-Beim-Bruce.jpg" />
```

**The CSS:**

```
img{border-radius:500px; border:2px solid #000000; width:200px; height:200px;}
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
img{
   border-radius:50%; 
   border:1px solid #000000;
   height:150px;
   width:200px;
}
/*You can change height width*/
```